# `spacy.Doc.from_bytes` keeps choking

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to serialize the docs in my pipeline so that I don't have to recompute them each time. I have English documents that are up to ~500,000 characters in length as well as metadata so I am first using `doc.to_bytes()` and then pickle to serialize each datum. But when I try to `Doc.from_bytes` I get the following error message:

```
*** Exception: Buffer exhausted at 78974/1476394825 symbols read.
```

Serialization code:

```
data['doc'] = pickle.dumps(doc.to_bytes())
```

Deserialization code:

```
serializer = spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab)
serializer.from_bytes(data['doc'])
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Expressions like `pickle.dumps(doc.to_bytes())` make it difficult to determine which function is causing the problem. Try splitting that statement so each function call is run un a separate statement, and at least that will clarify whether the problem is occurring in `doc_to_bytes` or `pickle`.

Comment: Right. I separated it out and it looks like the problem isn't with `doc.to_bytes()` but rather with pickling large files. Apologies for not following through before posting. Now I am encountering another problem with deserializing the bytes string using the `from_bytes` method. It is not well-documented and it's unclear how to initialize the Doc object. Seems a bit backwards to me since from_bytes should (in my mind) be a pure function with the type signature, `from_bytes: bytes -> Doc`.

Comment: I've made some progress that somehow the deserializing depends on the nlp object, whose state changes depending on what it's seen (e.g. vocabulary) in any given pipeline.

Comment: Had you thought of trying other serialization technologies? The shelve module might make this easier, for example.